# Semilinear elliptic equations in complex plane

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, cv.complex-variables, elliptic-pde

Let $D$ denote the closed unit disk centered at the origin in the complex plane. Let $F: D \times \mathbb C \to \mathbb C$ be a smooth function. Is there any theory for well-posedness (in the sense of existence and uniqueness of solutions) for semilinear equations of the form
$$ -\Delta u + F(x,u) = 0 \quad \text{on $D$},$$
with Dirichlet data $u=g$ on $\partial D$ where $g$ is **complex valued**.

(A suitable answer would say that for certain classes of $F$ the above PDE has a unique solution for any complex valued $g$ in certain Sobolev spaces with continuous dependence of solutions with respect to $g$. This question is rather classical if you focus on real valued functions $g$ but I could not find any good theory for complex valued Dirichlet data.)

Comment: I think there are several textbooks which treat complex function spaces and associated trace theorems without further ado, off the top of my hat I would say the book of Leoni (First Course in Sobolev Spaces) will surely have it.

Comment: But you know that I am talking about solving nonlinear equations not just complex functional spaces right?

Comment: I am aware, yes; from your answer I gain that apparently I seem not to detect the fundamental problem here..